# Recovery of a lost word document

Tags: microsoft-word

I was writing in Word and saved a file. Using the same document, I erased what I had and wrote something different, but instead of saving it under a different name, I hit the automatic save button. I have checked the document and it has no previous versions listed. How do I get the first document back?

Answer (score 0):

Scavenge the drive with something like [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva).

Because you 'intentionally' overwrote it rather than trashed it, there is no 'easy route' to getting it back.

Of course, installing a recovery app you don't already have on your machine will increase the chances of the file's original location being overwritten

You might be better using a different computer, downloading the [portable version](https://www.piriform.com/recuva/features/portable-version) & running it from a bootable USB stick.

The less writes you do to that machine, the better your chances of recovery.